# How to View source page using Wireshark?

Tags: networking, gzip, wireshark, pcap, chunked-encoding

Is there a possibility that a website's source page can be captured and viewed using Wireshark ? I do not need the header packets, what I am looking for is the full source page of any site that I open while running the Wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - in the list of packets, right-click and say "Follow TCP Stream".  For uncompressed content, that's it.

If the content is gzipped, you need to save that output to a file, use a decent text editor (that won't break binary content) to strip away the headers, then run gunzip to decompress it.

(If anyone knows of a way to make Wireshark do all that itself, I'm all ears!)

**Edit**: Just noticed the 'chunked-encoding' tag... that makes it harder.  Editing away the chunk headers in the text editor should be possible, but tedious if there are a lot of them.

Comment: I think what he is looking for is un-GZipped (uncompressed and decoded) reassembled data. Can you name any decent text editor that can strip away the headers (I have used the Notepad++ but failed :-( ).

Comment: @AbhineetK7: I've used SciTE for this job before.